# How to short motor terminals using Sabretooth 2x32?

Tags: motor

I am using a Sabretooth 2x32 motor driver and an Arduino Uno for control via serial.

I am unable to brake the motor using the Sabretooth whereas if I manually short the motor terminals by hand, they are locked. I have disabled freewheeling on the Sabretooth.

Does anyone have any idea what setting is required to brake motors using Sabretooth?

For reference, I have these [motor drivers](https://www.dimensionengineering.com/products/sabertooth2x32). [Product Spec](https://www.dimensionengineering.com/products/sabertooth2x32).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the sabertooth data sheet under Additional Commands, you'll see that by sending `M1:shutdown\r\n` the motor will hard brake and `M1:startup\r\n` will resume motor control for the motor.

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice that. I will try out the results tomorrow at my lab and get back.